# FullCalendar Events lose user data after renderEvent or updateEvent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar

I have event objects I load into fullcalendar. Each event has a custom `resources` array field attached showing who the events are for. Loads fine. User can click on the event and `eventClick` gives me the event with the `resources`. I open a dialog to edit. After saving changes to the db, I want to update the calendar using `updateEvent`. The object I use to update contains the full `resources` array and all appears to update fine.

Here's the problem: Now when I click on the same event to edit again, the event returned by `eventClick` has the `resources` array length set to 0. i.e. all the `resources` elements are missing.

Thought maybe I wasn't updating with the 'original object' so tried `removeEvents` followed by `renderEvent` but get the exact same behavior.

What am I missing?

btw, using fullCalendar 1.6. I can just reload the calendar and it's fine, but I don't want to 'cause it flickers and means unnecessary bytes over the wire.

**update**
So if I use `appointment.resources = angular.copy(appointment.resources)` then everything works. I'm not clear on why though. Is it because the attached resources were from an angular $resource and when that refreshed the reference to the previous objects point nowhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be a reference problem.

When you create a fullCalendar event, it wraps the object to a new one.
So, if you do something like:

```
var myEvent = {id: 1, title: "MyTitle", resources:[1,2,3], start:moment()};
$.('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', myEvent);
```

It create another object, with some specific properties like backUps, specific methods, etc... You can access this object with:

```
var fcEvent = $.('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', myEvent.id);
```

But now:

```
fcEvent.resources != myEvent.resources
```

Anyway, is difficult to know exactly what's the problem without a piece of code. Is possible to create a Plunker?

You can use my [public Skeleton for ui-calendar](http://plnkr.co/edit/kZgX6j?p=preview)